# React-Native, keeping new lines "\n" from database

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to pull data from a database which provides a `JSON` response.

However no matter what I try, putting the variable into a `<Text>` prop always `prints` the `"\n"` as text on screen.

Is there any way either `client` or `server` side to allow new lines to properly make there way into the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how I handled this on my client side:

```
var response = fetch(...);
response = response.replace(/\\n/g,'\n');
```

Comment: I would use `response.replace(/(?:\\r)?\\n/g, '\n');` This also supports Windows line endings `\r\n`.

Comment: Even better.. Though he asked specifically about '\n'.