# \n is not rendering the text in new line

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having some dynamic JSON strings like below:

```
Status is unknown\nThe combination is excluded by the following restriction\nRestriction number 2. 01 Mar 12 08:03:01 0--Exclusion--OrderDeliveryTimeframe.equals(\"oneMonth\") && OrderShipping.equals(\"air\")\n\n
```

So when I am printing the same as output, `\n` is not rendering the text in new line. So I wrote the below code:

```
return <div>
  {item.intro.replace(/[\n \n\n]/g, "\n")}
     <br/>
```

Now the problem is - It is rendering the text in next line after encountering first occurrence of`\n`, but not after that. Neither it is working for `\n\n`. I think I am missing something. Can someone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line break in HTML with '\n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`\n` isn't a newline in HTML, it's just a space. Any series of whitespace characters in HTML is treated as *one* space.

The React part of this is how you use `br` elements to do what you want to do.

The easiest way is to tell the `div` to treat whitespace different, [as discussed in this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n).

```
return <div style={{whiteSpace: "pre-line"}}>
    {item.intro}
</div>;
```

Or you could wrap the lines with an element, such as a `div` or `p`:

```
return <div>
    {item.intro.split(/\n/).map(line => <div key={line}>{line}</div>)}
</div>;
```

Or if you want `br` elements between the lines, you can use fragments:

```
return <div>
    {item.intro.split(/\n/).map(line => <React.Fragment key={line}>{line}<br/></React.Fragment>)}
</div>;
```

*(We can't use the shorthand `<>___</>` form because they don't support keys.)*

But I don't like that last one as it ends with a `<br/>`. You can fix that, but it's more complicated:

```
return <div>
    {item.intro.split(/\n/).map((line, index) => index === 0 ? line : <React.Fragment key={line}>{line}<br/></React.Fragment>)}
</div>;
```

Comment: For those looking for a React Native solution see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41908800

Answer (score 5):

How about with only css `white-space:pre` :

---

You can run the below script, Hope that will help.

```js
const { useState , useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {

  const nstr = "Hi Vivek \nHow are you \n\nGlad to see you there";

  return (
    <div class='new-line'>
      { nstr }
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```css
.new-line {
 white-space:pre
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably one solution if you [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string by `\n` then using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) rendering each element from the iteration between `<p>` tags.

Try as the following:

```
return <div>
  {
     item.intro.split('\n')
               .map(e => <p>{e}</p>)
  }
</div>
```

You would have similar result then - this is not using **JSX**, just for representation:

```js
const text = 'random\ntext\nhello';
const div = document.getElementById('text');
const result = text.split('\n').map(e => `<p>${e}</p>`);

div.innerHTML = result.join('');
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Split the string using `\n` and then display them by looping the resulting array. This way the expected output will be obtained. Hope this helps

```js
var text = "Status is unknown\nThe combination is excluded by the following restriction\nRestriction number 2. 01 Mar 12 08:03:01 0--Exclusion--OrderDeliveryTimeframe.equals(\"oneMonth\") && OrderShipping.equals(\"air\")\n\n
";
    return (
    <div>
        {text.split("\n").map((t,key) => {
            return <p key={key}>{t}</p>;
        })}
    </div>);
```